# Нужно вывести в print изначально введённое значение n

Tags: python-3.6

Пишется код для перевода числа из десятичной системы счисления в любую другую. Вот такой:

```
def y():
    n = int(input('Число по основанию 10: '))
    a = int(input('Основание системы, в которую нужно перевести число: '))

    b = ''

    while n > 0:
        b = str(n % a) + b
        n = n // a

    print(n, ' по основанию', a, 'равно ', b)

y()
while True:
    flag = input('Введите 1, чтобы посчитать ещё: ')

    if flag == '1':
        y()
    else:
        break
```

В целом всё работает, но команда print должна выводить изначально введённое значение n, но она всегда выводит значение аргумента n равным 0:

```
0 по основанию .. равно ..
```

Comment: Ну сохраните введённое значение `n` в другую переменную, да хоть в `m` и печатайте потом эту переменную вместо `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этой части кода

```
while n > 0:
    b = str(n % a) + b
    n = n // a
```

вы сначала **изменяете** значение в переменной `n`, пока цикл не завершится - и он совершится, **когда оно будет равно нулю.**

Затем вы этот нуль выводите:

```
print(n, ' по основанию', a, 'равно ', b)
```

Чтобы этого не произошло, **сохраните оригинальное значение переменной `n`** в другой переменной и выводите его. Например так:

```
orig_n = n
while n > 0:
    b = str(n % a) + b
    n = n // a

print(orig_n, ' по основанию', a, 'равно ', b)
```

Comment: Но правильнее было бы вынести в функцию.